# Jquery Validation Plugin Auto Validation for SELECT

Tags: jquery, validation, select

I'm using JQuery Validation Plugin to validate a form and I wanted to turn off the auto validation for the fields when you type or tab out of the fields, so I added:

onkeyup: false,
onfocusout: false

to the validate() options....but the problem is that I have one dropdown () and after the "required" rule has triggered and I select a value and tab to the next field, the error message for the dropdown disappears, which I don't want. I want the validation to only trigger when the visitor clicks "submit". Everything is working as expected for the input fields.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is written in the official docs, that there's another possible validation callback:

> onclick
>
> Type: Boolean or Function()
>
> Validate checkboxes and radio buttons on click. Set to false to disable.

However, when I opened `jquery.validate.js` and looked at callbacks list, I saw in the comments, that `click` event is used to validate select fields as well.

**The final code to disable auto validation:**

```
$('form').validate({
    onclick: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    onfocusout: false
});
```